# Configuring a Content Control in Word to add New Lines

Tags: java, ms-word

I'm using a content control in a Word template into which I programmatically add text (using java). This works fine. Now I would like to insert a new line at each new sentence in the text. Is there a way to configure the content control so that it automatically does this?

Comment: When you say "new line" do you mean a new paragraph, or a soft return?  Are you content controls block level (ie contain paragraphs), or inline?

Comment: The content controls do not contain paragraphs. Each sentence should appear on a new line ( a hard return after each sentence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid you cannot configure Content Controls to do this automatically.

However, if you fill the Content Controls via the Word object model, you could simply use a Rich Text Content Control or a Plain Text Content Control, the latter with the option to "allow carriage returns (multiple paragraphs)" (MultiLine in the object model) activated, and fill it with text containing line breaks.

For a quick test I have added such a Plain Text Content Control to an empty document and used the following VBA code:

```
Sub FillContentControl()
    ContentControls(1).Range.Text = "Sentence One." & vbNewLine & "Sentence Two."""
End Sub
```

In my example, this produced the following output:

```
Sentence One.
Sententce Two.
```

You should of course rather add the linebreaks in your Java code. You will just have to detect where your sentences end.

If, as your request for a docx4j-based solution indicates, you do not fill out your Content Control via Word but directly into the docx, I could think of another workaround involving a VBA Macro (which I usually would not recommend): You could add an event handler for the Document.Open event to update all flagged Content Controls in the document. It could look like this:

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
    For Each ContentControl In ThisDocument.ContentControls
        If ContentControl.Tag = "TODO_Add_Linebreaks" Then
            ContentControl.Range.Text = Replace(ContentControl.Range.Text, ". ", "." & vbNewLine)
            ContentControl.Tag = ""
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This second solution requires that you add your Content Controls with the Tag "TODO_Add_Linebreaks" (or whatever indication you prefer) and that you make your documents Macro-enabled.

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me how you added the VBA code to the Content Control?

Comment: I have not added the VBA code to the Content Control but to the document solely for testing. Adding code to a Content Control is not possible. If you really want the line breaking to happen in your document instead of your Java code, you could write a handler for the Document.Open event and process all your ContentControls to add the line breaks. I will update my answer to show you the necessary steps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, you win the bounty!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [w:br](http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/ecma376/WordML/br.html) element, like so:

```
<w:p>
  <w:sdt>
    <w:sdtPr>
      <w:id w:val="711844519"/>
    </w:sdtPr>
    <w:sdtContent>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>foo</w:t>
        <w:br/>
        <w:t>bar</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:sdtContent>
  </w:sdt>
  <w:r>
</w:p>
```

For how to add one of those using docx4j, see [linebreaks-in-strings](http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/linebreaks-in-strings-t1663.html#p5565)

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to configure the Content Control itself rather than using Java but will try this if there is no other option.